# Perl terminate command on handle close

Tags: perl, command

I have the following code which reads output from the command 'some_command'. The 'some_command' is an ongoing process which keeps printing output until it is killed. I am wondering if I close the file handle or call on last, will it also terminate the 'some_command' process or it's possible that 'some_command' will keep running as an orphan process. I basically want to read output from the command until I find the line with /Output/ then terminates.

```
my $mycommand = 'some_command';
open IN, "$mycommand 123456 |" or die("Failed: $!");
while(my $line = <IN> && !$stop) {
    if($line =~ /Output/) {
       # work is done
       last;
       $stop = 1;
    }
}
close IN;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close` on this type of handle will start by closing the pipe, then it waits for the child to exit. The child will die from a SIGPIPE the next time it tries to write to the pipe. If you don't want to wait that long, you can speed things along and terminate it yourself.

```
my $pid = open ...;
while (<IN>) {
    if (/Output/) {
       # work is done
       kill TERM => $pid;
       last;
    }

    print;  # Or whatever
}

close IN;
```

(Got rid of `$stop` since you weren't using it.)

Comment: In the example you provided above, I don't have to call close IN?

Comment: @user1540909, I didn't mean to omit it. If you don't close it explicitly, it's going to get closed on exit. Although... if you use a package variable (as you are) instead of lexical, a wontfix bug in Perl makes it so Perl doesn't `wait` for the child.